# Using FuzzyFinder in vim (+MiniBuffer), open file in current buffer

Tags: editor, vim, fuzzy, fuzzyfinder

I'm using FuzzyFinder in vim together with MiniBufExplorer (with this setting in my .vimrc: g:miniBufExplorerMoreThanOne = 1).

I'm using FuzzyFinder in coverage-file mode (where it works pretty much like command-t, from what I understand).

The problem is, whenever I use FuzzyFinder to open a new file, instead of opening it in the current window I have open, it creates a new, tiny vertically-split window.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

EDIT: This only happens with the new, modified version of minibuffer (linked to from the vim script page). Not sure what I can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to open the file with FuzzyFinder? If you check :help fuf-options you'll see this is all configurable and it's possible to open in the current window, a new split window, and a new vertically split window, all using different key combinarions. You're interested in opening in the current window.

Run this:

```
:let g:fuf_keyOpen
```

It will tell you the proper key to open the file without first splitting the window.

Comment: That gives me <CR>. This problem *only* happens when I've got the minibufexplorer window open; when I close it and try switching files, it works perfectly. This is why I think it's a problem with the interaction between them.

Comment: yes this answer is wrong. Opening the current window is what is messing up in combination with minibufexpl. The auestion is how to fix that